# Can current absorbed by a shield of a cable be harmful to a human?

Tags: grounding, shielding

I wonder if I should isolate shielding everywhere throughout the system. It is a bit costly because shields are on the outside and tend to touch a bunch of outer metal parts. But then humans can touch those parts too.

For example here is a GX connector I am using:

[image]

I just let the shield go through the outer metal casing here. So I, and others, will touch the shield every time we connect/disconnect this plug. The maximum voltage on the system this connects to is 12V and the shield is not connected to anything within the system (the ground is separate).

I keep wondering if that is a good idea. What if:

- a high voltage cable falls down on this cable and charges the shield?
- a lightning strikes the cable while someone is holding it? (there is a very small probability of that)

Those are outside/third-party threats so should I consider them? Are there any rules regarding selling a system that has this potential vulnerability? Should I invest in a 5-pin connector instead an run the shield inside through a pin? But then wouldn't that expose the wires within the connectors to noise?

Comment: Shields need to be grounded to work so I don't know what you mean when you say they aren't. You also did not describe your system despite seeming to be concerned about things which essentially equate to being struck by lightning which insulation won't protect you from anyways. That bolt just traveled hundreds of feet through air. A few mm of rubber isn't going to stop it.

Comment: @DKNguyen I mean they are not connected to the ground wire within the main circuit. They are grounded separately. Good point about the lightning strike. So it is down to having a high voltage wire leak to the shield.

Comment: hat is fine. The point is that there is an easier path to ground it can take rather than needing to get there by detouring through your body. I still don't advise you to hang onto a cable when its struck by lightning though since there are non-idealities.  Charge absorbed by a conductor though can be harmful to a person since when they touch it, some of it will travel to them in order to equalize the charge between both bodies. (Your car chassis being struck by lightning for example but sitting on the ground with rubber tires).But if it's grounded that charge will drain.

Comment: @DKNguyen So is there only a risk if someone forgets to connect the shield to ground or breaks that connection?

Comment: There's always risk no matter what. There are also transient effects such as inductance that come into play since cable is not a perfect conductor that provides a zero effort path to ground around your body. Remember, you could be standing next to a tree when it's struck by lightning and the bolt could jump from the tree to you and then to ground, rather than just travelling through the tree to ground. There's only so much you can do.

Comment: There's always risk no matter what. There are also transient effects such as inductance that come into play since cable is not a perfect conductor that provides a zero effort path to ground around your body. Remember, you could be standing next to a tree when it's struck by lightning and the bolt could jump from the tree to you and then to ground, rather than just travelling through the tree to ground. Or the tree can explode while you stand next to it as the lightning travels through it to ground. There's only so much you can do.

Comment: Covering shields is not a standard practice. I would suggest you don't worry about it. Instead, make sure that all harmful voltages are installed and used in compliance with the electrical code where you live, and all products are tested by the relevant regulatory agency (UL, or CSA or have CE mark, etc). If you have a question about how to design something to comply with those regulations, that could be a legitimate question.